# Assign the query result before with?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variable-assignment, common-table-expression

I am writing a piece of dynamic SQL which requires a `with` statement and passes out results.

I am restricted to assign variables in-between script. I need to return the result before the whole with query.

What I want to do is to write the following script as an example.

```
set @variable = (
  with temp as (
    select number from data
  )
  select avg(number) from temp
)
```

But with doesn't return the result.

Is there an intelligent way to get around this problem?

I know I can assign variable after `***select***` as `select @variable = avg(number)...`, which I am not allowed to do

Comment: "which I am not allowed to do" - you might have an XY problem. what's the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Why did someone tell you you're not about to use `select @variable = avg(number)`? There's literally nothing "wrong" with that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

What about doing it this way?

```
set @variable = (
select avg(number) 
from (select number 
             from data)
)
```

Comment: I am writing a dynamic SQL to query different tables. The fore-script set @variable is fixed.

Comment: right, i am just not skillful enough to do the query without with...

Comment: *"I am writing a dynamic SQL to query different tables"* Then show us the *actual* statement that generates your queries.

Answer (score 0):

When using a CTE, you need to declare the CTE at the *start* of the statement, not in the middle of it. In this case, that would mean:

```
WITH CTE AS( --A CTE isn't a temporary object, so calling it temp seems silly
    SELECT number
    FROM data)
SELECT @variable = AVG(number)
FROM CTE;
```

But there's really no need for a CTE here. You could simply write the statement as below:

```
SELECT @Variable = AVG(number)
FROM data;
```

If you prefer `SET` you could do something like this, but the previous statement is the shortest:

```
SET @Variable = (SELECT AVG(number) FROM data);
```

Comment: i haven't thought about it clearly yet. do you mean for every with statement, there is a equivalent way to right it without with?